# OCaml: type definition syntax

Tags: ocaml

I read a program with the following definition:

```
type 'a queue = ('a list * 'a list) ref
```

I do not understand the syntax here. Is it a union or what?

Answer (score 2):

This is a synonym/alias. The type `('a list * 'a list) ref` already makes sense in OCaml (it is a reference to a pair of lists of type `'a`), we are giving it a new, shorter name, `'a queue`. More precisely, `queue` is the name of a parametrized type, and the parameter is named `'a` here.

Comment: Hi, also I do not know how to define a queue using this parametrized type. Could you help me about this?